# English term for "Nebenteil"

Tags: translation-request, mathematical-german

In almost any German book on the theory of functions the term "Nebenteil" is used for the part of a Laurent series which has non-negative exponents.
E. g., if the Laurent series $\sum_{\nu = -\infty }^\infty a_\nu z^\nu$ is given, the "Nebenteil" would be $$\sum_{\nu = 0}^\infty a_\nu z^\nu.$$

I know that the part $\sum_{\nu = -\infty}^{-1} a_\nu z^\nu$ is called principal part in English literature but what is the English term for "Nebenteil".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: translating it means "additional part".

Comment: I don't know that I've come across a term for it, but if you were to call it the "singular part", I think most people would be able to understand what you meant without you having to define it explicitly.

Comment: Most don't use a special term, but some seem to call it "analytical part".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_part This wikipedia entry suggest the name "regular part". I would adopt it in my writing.

Comment: Thanks to everyone.
I think the term regular part fits best for my purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A randomly selected old German math text (Otto Dziobek's 1910  [*Vorlesungen über Differential- und Integralrechnung*](https://books.google.com/books?id=pJUtAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA171&lpg=PA171&dq=nebenteil&source=bl&ots=i9WUG7wPgk&sig=t94nTWO1uMeKjuKEXq9DtPAncF0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwja15PyrYfZAhVop1kKHRydBmoQ6AEIczAP#v=onepage&q=nebenteil&f=false) at p170 uses *Hauptteil* and *Nebenteil* where I would use *main term* and *remainder*. (In discussing the definition of derivative, $f(x+dx) = f(x)$ plus an infinitesmal  *Nebenteil*).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This sounds like a viable translation. Unfortuntelly ,in my case I don't need (and so I don't want) to explicitly speak of the main term (Hauptteil). Thus, in this context remainder would by to vague.
Anyway, I'm going to accept your answer because I'm sure it will help if someone else stumbles upon this question

Comment: Thanks!  I like your phrase "a viable translation", and agree with your usage judgement.